# If $G(k')$ is dense in a geometrically reduced group scheme $G$ then $G(k')$ is dense in $\vert G_{k'}\vert$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

As in 1.9 of Milne's note [Algebraic Groups](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf), it is said that if $G/k$ is a geometrically reduced group scheme, then for a field extension $k'$ of $k$, $G(k')$ is dense in $G$ if and only if $G(k')$ is dense in $\vert G_{k'} \vert$. Here $G(k')$ is dense in $G$ means that if a closed subscheme $Z \subset G$ satisfies $Z(k') = G(k')$ then $Z=G$.

The if part is easy. But why the only if part is true?

Comment: Use the following. Let $X$ be an algebraic scheme over a field $k$, and let $Z$ be a closed
subscheme of $X$. If $|Z|=|X|$ (meaning max specs) and $X$ is reduced,
then $Z=X$. For example, if $X=Spm(A)$ is affine, then $Z=Spm(A/I)$ for some
ideal $I$ in $A$. By hypothesis $I$ is contained in all maximal
ideals of $A$, but their intersection is $0$ (Nullstellensatz).

Comment: @anon This is not quite the same. Let $Y^{k'}$ be the closure of (image of) $G(k')$ in $G$ and $\tilde{Y}^{k'}$ be the closure of $G(k')$ in $G_{k'}$. There is no way that $Y^{k'}\times \mathrm{Spec}{k'} = \tilde{Y}^{k'}$. What you can conclude from the condition and using your criterion is that $Y^{k'}=G$. But who knows that $ \tilde{Y}^{k'}=G_{k'}$?

Comment: If a closed subscheme becomes equal to $X$ after a field extension, then it was already equal to $X$ (obviously).

Comment: @anon I mean, what you need to show is that $\tilde{Y}^{k'} = G_{k'}$. But $\tilde{Y}^{k'}$ is not base change of any thing.

Comment: @anon The link works for me here. It is just linked to Milne's note you said.